# Modal View controller not displaying at Center

Tags: objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller

![I am working on an ipad app where i have to display a table view as form sheet, when i click a cell in the table the form should resize ][1]

I wrote this code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 620);
}
```

and when a cell is clicked i wrote `self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 620);`   in did select row at index path.... both these times the form sheet is not displayed in the center. Where am i going wrong. Is there any other method to implement this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7 You cannot adjust the size of a modally presented view controller anymore.

You want to use the `UIModalPresentationStyleCustom` mode and then supply your own custom transition using the new APIs available in iOS 7+

See the following links for more info:

http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html
http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/
http://objectivetoast.com/2014/03/17/custom-transitions-on-ios/

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details? Basically it seems like your form view needs to be have AutoResizingMasks properly set (example):

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

i.e.:

**self.yourContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;**

Moreover setting your Form view center to view center would also help like:

**yourformView.center=self.view.superview.center;**

This will also make your form position at center (Horizontally and vertically both).

Hope this might help, not sure about your exact scenario but more details might help though if above answer didn't help.